# Mysql Query order by most liked

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

i am trying to run a mysql query to order by most liked.

this is my select statment.

```
 SELECT * FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta .post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'liked_count'
```

But what i need to do is order by most liked which would be fine if it was just a number in the field ie.

```
 SELECT * FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta .post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'liked_count'
ORDER BY liked_count DECS
```

But here is what i get in the fields???

How can i order by the a:2 value ????

```
a:2:{i:9;s:10:"user_likes";i:1;s:10:"user_likes";}
```

This worked

```
   SELECT * FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta .post_id
WHERE meta_key = 'liked_count'
ORDER BY meta_value DESC
```

Comment: Is this a self-answered question? *i'm confused*

Comment: Assume we don't know the wordpress schema, because most of us don't ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use column_number in "Order by".

```
    SELECT * FROM wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta .post_id
    WHERE meta_key = 'liked_count'
    ORDER BY 3 DESC --(say, if meta_value is 3rd  column in result table)
```